# Editing something in Column Section

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

How do I edit/rename a certain section in a column?

[image: Image of Column]

I'm looking to change "Spanish Lab Report Card" to "Spanish Lab Report Card 2".

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio for this project.

Comment: You don't, you `UPDATE` the value in the column row with the *new* value. You don't "edit" a value. Though, likely, you could use something like `REPLACE` to generate the new value, if you wished.

Comment: @ktestcody You would use an UPDATE statement. Are you using a SQL query window with a SELECT statement to retrieve the data to view it?

Comment: @MintBerryCRUNCH Yes, I am using SQL query window with SELECT to retrieve the data to view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SQL query window you would need to run a statement like the below. This would update all the records in the ReportName field with the name "Spanish Lab Report Card" to "Spanish Lab Report Card 2".

```
    UPDATE table_name 
    SET ReportName = 'Spanish Lab Report Card 2'
    WHERE ReportName = 'Spanish Lab Report Card'
```

Note this will update ALL the records with the name 'Spanish Lab Report Card' in the ReportName field.